# Does "anathema" need an "an"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, articles

[Anathema is a noun<sup>Ref</sup>.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anathema) And, nouns generally need articles in certain kinds of sentences.

Consider:

```
Jane is _______.
```

Then:
`Jane is a cat.` is proper but `Jane is cat.` (no article) is not proper.

However, I see both usages for "anathema":
`Jane is anathema.` and `Jane is an anathema.`.

As in [these examples from Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anathema#example-sentences):

> - Risk assessment **is anathema** to most environmental groups.
> - That's **an anathema** to most mainstream journalists.
> - They are close lipped, secretive **and anathema** to the open stadards[sic] movement.

**Shouldn't "anathema" almost always have an article (an) in front of it?**
If not, why not? (other than a bunch of people have already used it improperly)

Is there a standard reference that allows this?  For example, I haven't yet found anything in *The Gregg Reference Manual*.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: Merriam-Webster defines *anathema*, in part, as:  *b :  someone or something intensely disliked or loathed —usually used as a **predicate nominative** <this notion was anathema to most of his countrymen — S. J. Gould>*

Comment: Also 'Jane is a nathema'

Comment: "Anathema" seems to function as a predicate adjective in many contexts. In particular, the third of your examples from Dictionary.com uses "anathema" in parallel with the adjective phrase "close lipped" and the adjective "secretive".

Comment: Strange that all the dictionaries classify it as a noun, I would've said it were an adjective.

Comment: I reckon it's down to the lazy tongue. 'An anathema' is a mouthful. That said, anathema is a noun. It deserves an article.

Comment: Since I hear _anathema_ as meaning poison, I would normally say "Turkey and peppermint is anathema to me," without any article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether you use the determiner 'an' depends on if you are using the word as a regular noun, a 'pseudo-adjective' or a predicate nominative.

As explained in a post on [fluther.com](https://www.fluther.com/38381/when-do-you-use-anathema-vs-an-anathema/) ; in which the person who answered the question, cites *Burchfield* and *Fowler’s Modern English Usage*.

> “The word anathema can be used as a regular noun (essentially meaning
>   “a thing cursed”) and a determiner can appear in front of it, “an
>   anathema.” However, it is usually used as what Burchfield calls a
>   “pseudo-adjective” or a predicate nominative (no determiner): “The
>   union was anathema to the middle management class.”
>
> Authority: The New Fowler’s Modern English Usage edited by R.W.
>   Burchfield. Clarendon Press: Oxford, England. 1996. Used with the
>   permission of Oxford University Press.”

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you correctly, whether to use the article depends on whether we want the 'noun' usage or some other usage.

Comment: I hadn't come across the term 'pseudo-adjective' before. Is it an offical term? Since it's been brought to my attention, I realise I use them a lot.

Comment: BTW, I think this answer will get many more upvotes if you give an easy to understand example of the usage of another pseudo adjective

Answer (score 7):

Here is an Ngram chart across the period 1700–2019 for "is an anathema" (blue line), "is anathema" (red line), "was an anathema" (green line) and "was anathema" (yellow line):

[image]

As you can see, the two forms without the indefinite article before *anathema* are far more common than the two forms with the indefinite article before *anathema*—and have been so for more than a century.

But an equally interesting Ngram chart compares "an anathema" (blue line), "anathema" (red line), and "anathemas" (green line) over the same period:

[image]

It is not at all surprising that the blue line for "an anathema" is always below the red line for "anathema," since any instance of the former is necessarily also an instance of the latter. But the frequency of "anathemas" (the green line) is markedly higher than the frequency of "an anathema," even though it is simply the plural form of "an anethema."

The few style guides I checked that discuss *anathema* at all seem not at all concerned about the issue of whether an indefinite article should precede it. The entry in Bergen Evans & Cornelia Evans, *A Dictionary of Contemporary American Usage* (1957) focuses entirely on the question of what the plural form should be:

> **anathema.** The plural is *anathemas* or *anathemata*, not *anathemae*.

And *Webster's Word Histories* (1989), despite devoting a full page to the word, never discusses the sometimes-present, sometimes-absent indefinite article at all, referring variously to "an anathema of oblivion," "offered up as an anathema," "Among the more famous anathemas," and "the mutual anathemas" and quoting Deuteronomy 7:26 in the Douay Bible as saying

> Neither shalt thou bring anything of the idol into thy house, lest thou become *an anathema*, like it. Thou shalt detest it as dung, and shalt utterly abhor it as uncleanness and filth, because it is **an anathema**.

and yet observe, in the next paragraph,

> All of the church councils since the Council of Nicaea [A.D. 325] have worded their dogmatic canons to include the sentence "If anyone says ... let him be **anathema**."

It's as though the book doesn't notice the shift from "an anathema" and "anathemas" to article-less "anathema"—or doesn't consider it important.

And yet dictionaries identify all of the meanings of *anathema*, whether presented with articles or without them, as nouns. *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011) makes this clear through its choice of examples to illustrate the different definitions:

> **anathema** *n., pl.* **-mas 1.** A formal ecclesiastical ban, curse, or excommunication. **2.** A vehement denunciation; a curse. "*the sound of a witch's **anathemas** in some unknown tongue*" (Nathaniel Hawthorne). **3.** One that is cursed or damned. **4.** One that is greatly reviled, loathed, or shunned. "*Essentialism—a belief in natural, immutable sex differences—is **anathema** to postmodernists, for whom sexuality itself, along with gender, is  a 'social construct*'" (Wendy Kaminer).

As presented above, definition 4 gives no hint as to why *anathema* appears in Kaminer's quotation without an article. And yet in the quotation *anathema* reads as though it were a stand-in for an adjective such as *monstrous* or *disgusting*. None of the reference works I consulted explain how this split in treatment arose, although it may very well go back to translations of the "let him be anathema" wording cited by *Webster's Word Histories* from the Council of Nicaea and subsequent church councils.

Comment: Summary:  "Historically, the article is most often omitted for anathema". So, per Gary above, this is evidence that anathema is most often used as a *predicate nominative*.  When can we say that the modern dictionaries are wrong and just call it an adjective? ;)

Comment: Is this really so different from many other words e.g. *hatred*, *inconsistency*, *collaboration*, *performance*,  which can be used both with and without determiners.

Comment: Wow, this is very helpful. How did you generate this graph? I'd love to be able to get usage information on my own.

Comment: @DeepakJoy: Google's [Ngram tool](https://books.google.com/ngrams) lets you make comparisons of the type used in my answer. Note that Ngram measures the relative frequency of occurrence of specified terms, not their absolute number of occurrences, year by year. The tool has several shortcomings, including an inability to handle hyphenated words, and it can yield misleading results if you aren't careful to avoid confounding variables. But as a way of showing the relative frequency of well-matched words or phrases over time, it can be quite illuminating.

Answer (score 5):

There are three reasons for preferring the shorter version. History and social identity:

> Let him be Anathema.   1 Cor xvi

Consider it as factitive:

> Jane is cook.   Let Jane be Judge.  Jane is Queen of the May.

Euphony

Comment: Not feeling this answer yet. (1) That Bible example is a misquote. The actual phrase is `..., let him be Anathema Maranatha.` (KJV, with most other English versions having the `Maranatha` in some form)  So, this may just be an early misuse or a deliberate, one-time, poetical construction.   ... (2) The "factitive" examples do not hold, as those are all formal titles in context. "Anathema" is not a formal title AFAICT. ... (3) Euphony might be okay, but that would also excuse all kinds of pigeon English that's not considered grammatically correct (yet).

Comment: Hoping for a more authoritative answer, but will accept this one in a day or 2 if nothing better comes along.

Comment: The Vulgate has: `"si quis non amat Dominum Iesum Christum sit anathema maranatha"`, so the English may just be a (slight) mistranslation, omitting the article as happened from time to time?

Comment: @Brock what matters the Latin? It's a translation  of the Koine Greek.  Anyway, *let him be anathema* is a good translation, and it's also in both Galatians 1:8 and 1:9 in a couple English translations, although many versions translate the word to *accursed*.

Comment: @Clare, the KJV was translated from a variety of languages and all checked against the Vulgate.  The Latin also matters because it suggests that the article was present in the original, whatever the language.  Finally, a translation that omits a whole concept, is NOT a good *translation*, no matter how often it is repeated. (But it may be a pithier sound bite.)

Comment: What article are you talking about? There's none in the Vulgate. (Which, again, I don't see the importance of: the KJV was certainly not meant to be faithful to it.) There is also no article in the Greek text.

Comment: @user1284969632635 'Let him be anathema' is arguably not in modern English and thus in need of translation. The Bible was not written for linguistics experts [alone].

Answer (score 1):

The question of the admissibility of articles is determined by whether a word is  a count or a non-count noun.

The OED gives the form and etymology of ***anathema*** as follows:

> Forms:  Pl. anathemas; also, in sense 3, anaˈthemata. Etymology: <
>   Latin anathema an excommunicated person, also the curse of
>   excommunication, < Greek ἀνάθεμα , originally ‘a thing devoted,’ but
>   in later usage ‘a thing devoted to evil, an accursed thing’ (see Rom.
>   ix. 3). Originally a variant of ἀνάθημα an offering, a thing set up
>   (to the gods), n. of product < ἀνατιθέναι to set up, < ἀνά up +
>   τιθέναι (stem θε- ) to place. Compare anathem n., and anatheme n.

The fact that a plural form is quoted would suggest that it is a count noun, and this is borne out by its etymology. An ***anathema*** was the Latin for an "excommunicated person".

However in almost all modern examples the word is expressed in non-count form, with no articles present.